# Using fstat between shm_open and mmap

Tags: linux, posix, shared-memory

I am in the process of porting existing Win32 code to Linux. On Windows, I have a "master" process, the "reader", which creates a shared memory object and then waits that some "slave" processes, the "writers", put datas in the shared memory, for processing.

Master process: the Win32 implementation relies on `CreateFileMapping( INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, [...]` followed by `MapViewOfFile`. The size of the shared memory si specified in the `CreateFileMapping` call. Passing 0 as last argument to the `MapViewOfFile` ensures that all the shared memory is mapped. On Linux, after some googling, I concluded that I should use `shm_open` + `ftruncate` + `mmap`.

Slave processes: the Win32 implementation is almost the same as in the Master process, except that `CreateFileMapping` is replaced by `OpenFileMapping`, and that `VirtualQuery` may be used to obtain the size of the shared memory.

On Linux, I have a problem: the "slave" processes must somehow "wait" for the `ftruncate` call to be completed in the "master" process. They can't do a `ftruncate` by themselves, as they have no ideas, yet, about the shared memory size.

Would it be OK for the "slave" processes to be polling on `fstat` beetwen `shm_open` and `mmap`? Or is it bad practice, and if yes, is there another way of mmapping the "good" size?

EDIT:

For the time being, I don't want to directly use the File System. I like the fact that I can create a "Named Shared Memory Object" by using a "name" which will work on the 2 platforms, as `"/MySharedMemName42"` and don't want to care with the location(s) of file(s). I may change my mind if it appears to be not realistic.

I know that the master process and the slaves processes have to cooperate, when using the shared memory. They do that with writing/reading the memory. The "problem" is that the shm_open/mmap may lead to SIGBUS in slaves if there is a race (ftruncate being late in the master). I tested that "fstat polling" does the trick, but want to know if it's seen as an awful hack, or a correct way to deal with the race.

Comment: How do you resolve the race between `CreateFileMapping` in the master and `OpenFileMapping` in the slaves ?

Comment: @chill What race? If OpenFileMapping fails, slaves do what they want (retry?). If OpenFileMapping  succeeds, they can MapViewOfFile without fear.

Comment: The key to any of this is cooperating processes.  Some systems have separate process at beginning and end of day to create and unlink their shared memory before an apps (serv or client) run.  Some have mechanisms (e.g. file locks, semaphore, etc) to coordinate the orderly loading of processes e.g. no server then no clients run.

Comment: @duck If I can avoid the beginning/end of day house keeping, I will greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the Windows CreateFileMapping call is an *atomic* version of the UNIX stanza "shm_open+ftruncate<del>+maybe-mmap</del>", thus the possibility on UNIX that clients can access the shared memory *before* it is properly sized.

So, your proposed use of `fstat` is fine.  It's [officially supported](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/fstat.html) by the POSIX shared memory option.  Your design appears to tolerate polling for the existence of the shared memory region, so polling for the correct size of it (or at least `st_size > 0`) should also be OK.

Alternatively, you could perhaps play with the *mode* of the shared memory region during open (O_CREAT|O_EXCL and 0600) and `fchown` it when ready — your subordinate processes, depending on UIDs and GIDs, would fail with ENOENT or EACCES until the memory was prepared.  Again this is a "polling" option.  You could also rename the shared memory itself (via Linux's `/dev/shm/`) after sizing it, but this is a non-POSIX convenience.

(Now, if your subordinates were *children* of the master, then you could rely on that venerable *NIX technique of process inheritance and switch to unnamed shared memory...)

Comment: Even with permissions you still have race conditions.  The bottom line is that if size == 0 (as it would be on a newly created segment) then the client has to backoff (somehow) or quit.  Or avoid the situation entirely by not running clients w/o a server.

Comment: CreateFileMapping is the atomic version of "shm_open+ftruncate". mmap is done with MapViewOfFile. Thanks.

Comment: @Duck, what race do you mean?  There is no race if the subordinates cannot successfully `shm_open()` the segment until after it has been `ftruncate()`d.  (The master has to create the shm object exclusively.)

Comment: @pilcrow, I read your answer and commented as I was running out the door and now I am having trouble reconstructing my thoughts.  This seems like it is a good solution for all the scenarios I can generate at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same problem on both platforms - you need the slaves to wait for the master to setup the shared area.

In the Windows case you have the slaves trying to open a file mapping with a specific
well-known name and retry if a mapping with that name does not exist.

While not an ideal solution, but you can do the same on Linux.

Note that you don't necessarily need a POSIX shared memory object. You can use an ordinary file.
First, create and set the file size with ordinary `open(2)` and `ftruncate(2)`, but using a
temporary unique randomly generated name.
Then `rename(2)` the file from the temp name to the well-known name.

Comment: See updated question. My Windows slaves can't crash with memory violation when they successfully open the object in a race with the master. Is your rename idea applicable to the POSIX shared memory object?

Comment: It's true the same race condition exists on both platform but I am not sure where you are going with the file idea.

Comment: @Duck I don't see a race *leading to crash* in the win32 version.

Comment: @manuel, I don't see why this necessarily leads to a crash on posix either.  At worst you should fail with EINVAL on the attempted mmap of zero length.

Comment: @Duck because if I don't use the fstat polling, I have to mmap with a known not null size (say: size of some "header") and if the master has not done the ftruncate, yet, then the slave will SIGBUS.